# Multiple List in One Full List (Not list in a list)

Tags: python, list

I have a list in each row in a dataframe and I want to merge it into one whole list.

```
data = {'row 1': ["text 1", "text 2", "text 3"],
        'row 2': ["text 4", "text 5", "text 6"],'row 3':["text 7", "text 8", "text 9"]
        }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['row 1','row 2','row 3'])
dataframe

expected output: ["text 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4", "text 5", "text 6", "text 7", "text 8", "text 9"]
```

I've tried the df.iterrows but it ended up as a list of multiple lists...

```
total =[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   total.extend(row)

output: [["text 1", "text 2", "text 3"],["text 4", "text 5", "text 6"],["text 7", "text 8", "text 9"]]
```

Comment: Please show a sample DF as code rather than an image.

Comment: Can you try row[:], please?

Comment: You could [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists).

Comment: Also, your code has an indentation error

Comment: edited :) sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.explode()`:

```
df.explode('col2').values.tolist()
```